# Required Hep for Call 2 way connection and call using new REST API 1.1

Tags: callfire

We are using [Call fire API](https://www.callfire.com/api-documentation/rest/version/1.1) in our application. We are moving to new REST API platform.

We need to connect / call with 2 numbers(two way connection).

With previous library we were using `createClickToCallCampaign(key, callerid, transferNumber, awayMessage)` and then `sendConnection(APIKey, Convert.ToInt32(campaignId), OtherContactNo, info, Convert.ToInt32(CallFireDelayMins)`

So as per this 2 way call gets connected.  With new [REST API](https://www.callfire.com/api-documentation/rest/version/1.1) platform how can we have 2 numbers connected? Please guide us.

Looking forward to proper helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at our new API 2.0. SendCall operation should be what you are looking for https://developers.callfire.com/docs.html#sendCalls